# iOS - Top Layout Guide height issues

Tags: ios, uikit, ios-autolayout

I am refactoring some views in my application regarding iPhone X constraints and moved a group of views into a TabBarController view with also a Navigation views. Everything working just fine but one thing. Well... There is always that "one issue left" thing, isn't?

So the issue that I have is that the Top Layout Guide is set high. And I don't want that. See screenshot about this issue.

[image]

I have set the top constraint of the labels "Maandag" and "Op afspraak" (top one) to 0. Well to the Top Layout Guide. All views that I converted to this TabBar view has this issue :( I am using Storyboards.

This is the result on device (same on all kind of devices)
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With iOS 11, Apple is [deprecating](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621367-toplayoutguide#) `top(bottom)LayoutGuide` and switching to the `safeAreaLayoutGuide`. In code, you could pin your view using `view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor`, but in storyboards you'll want to pin stuff to the safe area node inside your view controller's view:

[image: interface builder safe area]

Comment: Okay so I added the Safe Area and those Top and Bottom Layout Guides got removed. But I still have that spacing, but now on the Safe Area :(

Comment: And your constraints say `top space to safe area 0`? Have you set any other properties on the table view that could affect this? Values for things like the content inset, automatically adjusts scroll view insets, table header height, section header height, etc. all have the potential to make the content appear inset from the top. I'd try creating a minimal new project with a similar layout from scratch and see if it looks how you'd expect. Then you can isolate the differences between it and your current project.

Comment: Your last comment gave me a good direction to look at other settings. Indeed there was one option checked on the ViewController itself. After disabling "Under Top Bars" in the attribute inspector, the issue seems to be resolved. Thanks a lot!!! Marked your post as answer too as this was also needed for me :)